# Trying to add dependency injection for binding object

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I'm working on web application based on .NET Core 2.0.
I have class `ReportModel`, which I use for binding parameters in controller method. And I also have some functionality in the same class (method `Get()` starts doing somethings, based on provided binded parameters), e.g:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetReport(ReportModel model)
    {
        return new JsonResult( new { model.Get().ToString() });
    }
```

Now I'm moving on `.NET 5` and want to add `IConfiguration` via **DI** to `ReportModel`.

I've expected it to work the follwing way: add constructor for `ReportModel` with `IConfiguration` for **DI** to provide configuration:

```
    public class ReportModel
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ReportModel(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
    ...
```

But when I try to run `GetReport(ReportModel model)` method it returns exception:
`InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'ViewData.Models.Data.ReportModel'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, give the 'data' parameter a non-null default value.`

A little explanation: there are few more classes, which I use this way (binding params to properties and storing functionality inside same class), so I don't really want to add each method `Get()` additional parameter for `IConfiguration`.

How am I supposed to do this properly? Am I missing something? Or It's just don't work this way?

I'm sorry if I use any of terminology wrong, would be glad if you point me the wrong stuff. Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't be passing in objects to the models, pass them into the controller instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How am I supposed to do this properly? Am I missing something? Or It's just don't work this way?

It doesn't work that way.

First of all, models are not supposed to have dependencies injected, they are just a class for getting the input from the request.

This is also wrong, though:  `... GetReport(ReportModel model)`. This relies on the fact that ASP.NET Core injects a new ReportModel by default - if this behavior changes, your code magically stops working.

Your code should look like this instead:

```
public class ReportsController
{
    private readonly IReportModelService _reportModelService;

    public ReportsController(IReportModelService reportModelService)
    {
        _reportModelService = reportModelService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetReport()
    {        
        return new JsonResult(_reportModelService.GetReport());
    }
}
```

Along with an appropriate class that builds the report, something like:

```
public class ReportModelService: IReportModelService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public ReportModelService(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public string GetReport()
    {
        // your logic here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a great question. You're on the right track.

In my opinion, the `ReportModel` simply shouldn't use dependency injection. The model should just be a property bag that models the incoming parameters.

Have logic be performed in a controller action (or otherwise handled some other way).

Answer (score 0):

So I listened the advice of @Camilo. My plan is to split `ReportModel` into `ReportParams` (DTO class) and `ReportProvider` (business logics class). Then, add constructor for `ReportProvider` in order to provide `IConfiguration` via **Dependency Injection** by calling `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ReportProvider>()`

Model splitting:

```
    public class ReportParams
    {
        public double Size { get; set; }
        
        // other properties.
    }

    public class ReportProvider
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public ReportProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public List<string> Get(ReportParams args)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

ReportController:

```
    public class ReportController: Controller
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

        public ReportController(IServiceProvider services)
        {
            _services = services;
        }

        public IActionResult Get(ReportParams args)
        {
            ReportProvider model = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ReportProvider>(_services);
            return JsonResult(model.Get(args));
        }
    }
```

Comment: " by calling `ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ReportProvider>()`" -> please, **no**! That's not Dependency Injection! You don't inject `IServiceProvider` unless you have a very advanced use-case that the framework can't solve, you inject (ask in the constructor) **directly** the service that you need (`ReportProvider` here)

Answer (score -2):

default DI container that is used in net core can only inject dependency inside of the constructor, in this case a controller constructor, not inside of an  action,  since action doesn't have a constructor. So change your code like this

```
public class ReportController
{
   private readonly ReportModel _model

  public ReportController(ReportModel model )
  {
   _model=model;
  }  

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetReport()
    {
        return new JsonResult( new { _model.Get().ToString() });
    }
}
```

and don't forget to add DI to the startup

```
services.AddScoped<ReportModel>();
```